# Поменять значение глобальной переменной внутри функцию

Tags: python

я хочу создать функцию в которой за аргумент будет приниматься глобальная переменная и внутри функции изменить значение этой переменной. Но изменений никаких не происходит

```
def tst(arg1,arg2):
    arg1 += 15
    arg2 = 17
    return arg1, arg2

abc = 15
zxc = 15
tst(abc,zxc)
```

`print(abc, zxc)` выводит: `abc = 15, zxc = 15`

В функции ниже я хочу повлиять на две переменные через аргументы. В переменную по аргументу arg_ret_index я хочу переназначить значение. Переменная по ключу arg_dict это словарь и я хочу добавить новое значение к существующему ключу в этот словаарь. Поидее манипуляция с добавлением нового значения в ключ не должна сработать. Потому что это словарь из глобальной переменной, но значение всё равно добавляется. Обьясните плз почему так происходит?)

```
def ZTE_HO_index(arg_dict, arg_key, arg_ret_index, start_i, finish_i):
    for i in range(start_i, finish_i):
        if i not in arg_dict[str(arg_key)]:
            arg_ret_index = i
            arg_dict[str(arg_key)] = arg_dict.get(str(arg_key), []) + [i]
            break
    return arg_ret_index
```

Comment: `abc, zxc = tst(abc, zxc)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы должны присвоить значения глобальным переменным:

```
def tst(arg1,arg2):
    arg1 += 15
    arg2 = 17
    return arg1, arg2

abc = 15
zxc = 15
abc, zxc = tst(arg1=abc, arg2=zxc)
print(abc, zxc) # выведет (30, 17)
```

Answer (score 3):

Всё, что вы делаете с аргументами функции, остаётся внутри функции. Потому что это копии значений внешних переменных, помещённые в переменные - аргументы функции. Какие бы вы вычисления и присваивания не делали - всё это пропадёт с окончанием функции, потому что это локальные переменные функции.

Есть несколько вариантов для функции что-то поменять вовне себя:

1. В явном виде вернуть результаты наружу через `return`. Это самый правильный способ, потому что "явное лучше неявного".
2. Получить доступ к глобальным переменным, объявив их внутри функции как `global` и присвоить им что нужно. Это плохой способ, так делать не рекомендуется. В идеале функция должна быть вещью в себе и знать о внешнем мире самый минимум в виде аргументов, которые она в явном виде получает на вход. Функция не должна ничего знать про какие-то ещё внешние переменные.
3. Ещё один способ - это получить на вход не простые переменные, а коллекции (например - список, словарь). С коллекциями функция тоже может что-то делать, как-то менять их содержимое, но опять же это не самый хороший способ, даже при таком подходе лучше не менять исходную коллекцию, а сделать её копию, поменять в ней что нужно, и вернуть в явном виде новую коллекцию.

P.S. Ещё раз про коллекции. Саму переменную - ссылку на коллекцию - вы поменять не можете, всё, что вы присвоите переменной аргументу функции наружу по-прежнему не уйдёт. А вот содержимое коллекции вам вполне доступно, потому что в функцию передаётся ссылка на коллекцию и по этой ссылке вы можете что угодно делать с **содержимым** коллекции - добавлять элементы, удалять и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ ! . Я добавил в вопрос вторую часть связанную с вашим ответом) У меня в моей функции работа с двумя глобальными переменными одна из них словарь. И в словарь изменения проходят, при том что я не использую return. Можете пожалуйста подсказать почему так происходит?)

Comment: @ralph_lauren Ну, собственно третий пункт у меня именно про это. Для понятности ещё в конце дописал пояснение.

Comment: Спасибо большое! теперь понял )

Comment: Спасибо большое! теперь понял )

Answer (score 1):

Можно так, но не рекомендуется.

```
# Глобальные переменные


a = 0


def change_the_sign_of_the_global_variable():
    global a
    a += 1


def main():
    change_the_sign_of_the_global_variable()
    print(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Суть в том чтобы использовать глобальную переменную внутри функции, нужно объявить её глобальной. Почитайте про область видимости.

Comment: Дело в том, что по моей задумке функция будет использоваться несколько раз и с разными переменными, по этому я не могу заранее объявить переменную глобальной, т.к. аргумент будет иметь разные переменные